# iOS NFC display time

Tags: ios, nativescript, nfc

I am working in Nativescript-Vue using the "nativescript-nfc" plugin.  So far it works really well, but I was wondering if its possible to make that NFC Popup go away quicker?  The "Ready to Scan" popup stays visible for about 3 seconds after a successful scan, but that isn't a great user experience.  I haven't seen anything in the plugin description for making it close immediately or within 1 second.

Comment: Have you set `stopAfterFirstRead ` to true? If then it usually stays for a second or so. Which device you are using to test? Moreover the developer have no control over the NFC Reader window, it's controlled by system. As soon the session is invalidated, it is going to show a checkmark and auto hide.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this:  `nfc.setOnNdefDiscoveredListener(
            data => {..},{stopAfterFirstRead: true}`
I am testing on a iPhone 8, but will eventually try to use an iPad.  I do see the checkmark, and auto hide works.  Its just a bit longer to auto-hide than I would prefer.